# Synchronizing skype contacts with android

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, skype

I installed skype on my android 2.3 samsung galaxy and all skype contacts were added to pnone contacts. Later in PC while using skype I renamed some of skype contacts and removed few of them. After that I ran skype on samsung again to find out the changes made in skype using it from PC were not applied to the skype version on samsung.

Do I need to manually synchronize skype contacts changes made in skype while using it on PC? And how to do it?